# How do I resolve this railties compatibility issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run bundle update I recieve this error:

> bundle update
>
> Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
>
> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
>      In Gemfile:
>       rails (= 3.2.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
>         railties (= 3.2.1) x86-mingw32
>
> ```
> sass-rails (= 3.2.3) x86-mingw32 depends on
>   railties (3.2.2.rc1)
> ```

I am new to Rails, and stackoverflow in general, I apologize for any layout inconveniences.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Edit 1: Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Please post you Gemfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your assets group in your Gemfile to remove the explicit versions:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Then update sass-rails:

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

Comment: Your sass-rails version is locked in your Gemfile, see my updated question.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall : where do we make this edit , i means where is Gemfile located

Comment: @Hussain Usually in your app’s root directory.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall : dev-kit , it should be inside ruby installed folder , after installation , right , but its not there , and i keep getting the error , correct your path or use dev kit , any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I get somewhat similar error...
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (= 3.2.1) x86-mingw32

```
jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
  railties (3.2.2.rc1)
```

I tried bundle install again after deleting Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

Running
    bundle update rails
solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery-rails dependencies specify railties >= 3.2.0.beta which is matching up with the 3.2.2 beta from last week, meanwhile rails still wants 3.2.1.

Related: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/pull/48

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when updating to Rails 4.1.3. Running bundle update is not a good practice, since it updates all the gems and on a large application it can be hard to fix all bugs you are going to have.
Instead, I updated at the same time the gems that were necessary:

```
bundle update rails sass-rails
```